# ncloc metric is missing in some of the Sonarqube 6.7 dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

- TeamCity Enterprise 9.1 (build 36973)
- Sonarqube Version 6.7.2 (build 37468)
- SonarC# 6.8.2 (build 4717)
- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2

Visual Studio build step (VS 2015) is called in between Sonarqube initiation and end steps. Build is successful without any issues in log and dashboard is also published. But Lines of Code information is missing from everywhere (Overview as well as Code tabs)

[image]

Any help around this is greatly appreciated.

```
Step 1/5: Init SonarQube (Command Line) (1s)        
Step 1/5] Starting: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\temp\agentTmp\custom_script7447098295248070367.cmd      
Step 1/5] in directory: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService     
Step 1/5] SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2       
Step 1/5] Default properties file was found at D:\Tools\SonarQubeRunner3\SonarQube.Analysis.xml     
Step 1/5] Loading analysis properties from D:\Tools\SonarQubeRunner3\SonarQube.Analysis.xml     
Step 1/5] *******.verbose=false was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Info'     
Step 1/5] Pre-processing started.       
Step 1/5] Preparing working directories...      
Step 1/5] 13:56:09.393  Updating build integration targets...       
Step 1/5] 13:56:09.413  Fetching analysis configuration settings...     
Step 1/5] 13:56:09.872  Generating rulesets...      
Step 1/5] 13:56:09.91  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...       
Step 1/5] 13:56:09.911  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...     
Step 1/5] 13:56:10.232  Generating rulesets...      
Step 1/5] 13:56:10.237  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...       
Step 1/5] 13:56:10.238  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...     
Step 1/5] 13:56:10.353  Pre-processing succeeded.       
Step 1/5] Process exited with code 0        
Step 2/5: Build (Visual Studio (sln)) (1m:09s)      
Step 2/5] Starting: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569 "/msbuildPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"       
Step 2/5] in directory: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569       
Step 2/5] Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Service.CashBalanceSheet.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build (1m)      
Step 2/5] Process exited with code 0        
Step 3/5: Move Binaries (Powershell)        
Step 4/5: Tests & Coverage (Powershell) (13s)       
Step 4/5] PowerShell Executable: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe      
Step 4/5] Working directory: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569      
Step 4/5] PowerShell arguments: [-Version, 2.0, -NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\temp\buildTmp\powershell5599767964486762314.ps1]      
Step 4/5] Process exited with code 0        
Step 5/5: Publish to SonarQube (Command Line) (25s)     
Step 5/5] Starting: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\temp\agentTmp\custom_script6141167007826015232.cmd      
Step 5/5] in directory: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569       
Step 5/5] SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2       
Step 5/5] Default properties file was found at D:\Tools\SonarQubeRunner3\SonarQube.Analysis.xml     
Step 5/5] Loading analysis properties from D:\Tools\SonarQubeRunner3\SonarQube.Analysis.xml     
Step 5/5] Post-processing started.      
Step 5/5] Fixed invalid Code Analysis ErrorLog file. Please check that VS 2015 Update 1 (or later) is installed. Fixed file: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Framework\Service.Authentication\bin\Release\Service.Authentication.dll.RoslynCA_fixed.json        
Step 5/5] WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\BDD_client\json\currencyCounterpart.json, project: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Service\Service.CashBalanceSheet.csproj     
Step 5/5] SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m        
Step 5/5] Calling the SonarQube Scanner...      
Step 5/5] INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\Tools\SonarQubeRunner3\*******-scanner-3.0.3.778\bin\..\conf\*******-scanner.properties      
Step 5/5] INFO: Project root configuration file: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\*******-project.properties      
Step 5/5] INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778     
Step 5/5] INFO: Java 1.8.0_20 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)       
Step 5/5] INFO: Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64        
Step 5/5] INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m        
Step 5/5] INFO: User cache: C:\Users\stabuild\.*******\cache        
Step 5/5] INFO: Publish mode        
Step 5/5] INFO: Load global settings        
Step 5/5] INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=187ms        
Step 5/5] INFO: Server id: AWJiow64LsT0HusiYL80     
Step 5/5] INFO: User cache: C:\Users\stabuild\.*******\cache        
Step 5/5] INFO: Load plugins index      
Step 5/5] INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=90ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.2      
Step 5/5] INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)      
Step 5/5] INFO: Process project properties      
Step 5/5] INFO: Load branch configuration       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load branch configuration (done) | time=3ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Load project repositories       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=215ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: Execute project builders        
Step 5/5] INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: Load quality profiles       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=39ms        
Step 5/5] INFO: Load active rules       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=828ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load metrics repository     
Step 5/5] INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=31ms      
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use *******.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.      
Step 5/5] INFO: Project key: Service.CashBalanceSheet       
Step 5/5] INFO: -------------  Scan Service.Referential     
Step 5/5] INFO: Load server rules       
Step 5/5] INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=277ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: Base dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Framework\Service.Referential     
Step 5/5] INFO: Working dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\.*******\mod4       
Step 5/5] INFO: Source paths: BalanceDate/CalculationDateMapper.cs, BalanceDate/DateCriteria.cs, BalanceDate/FunctionDateMapper.cs, BalanceDate/ICalculationDateMapper.cs, BalanceDate/IFunctionDateMapper.cs, Entities/BookingEntity.cs, Entities/Bucket.cs, Entities/Currency.cs, Entities/FunctionDate.cs, Entities/FunctionDates.cs, Entities/ProfitCenter.cs, Entities/ReferentialConstants.cs, Entities/StarModule.cs, BalanceDate/CalculatedFunctionDate.cs, IReferentialService.cs, Loader/BookingEntityLoader.cs, Loader/CurrencyLoader.cs, Loader/Dao/BookingEntityDao.cs, Loader/Dao/CurrencyDao.cs, Loader/Dao/IBookingEntityDao.cs, Loader/Dao/ICurrencyDao.cs, Loader/Dao/IProfitCenterDao.cs, Loader/Dao/IScheduleDao.cs, Loader/Dao/ProfitCenterDao.cs, Loader/Dao/ScheduleDao.cs, Loader/FunctionDateLoader.cs, Loader/IBookingEntityLoader.cs, Loader/ICurrencyLoader.cs, Loader/IFunctionDateLoader.cs, Loader/IProfitCenterLoader.cs, Loader/IScheduleLoader.cs, Loader/IUnitLoader.cs, Loader/ProfitCenterLoader.cs, Loader/ScheduleLoader.cs, Loader/UnitLoader.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, ReferentialService.cs, Entities/Unit.cs, Report/ReportTypeEnum.cs, Zone/IZoneLoader.cs, Zone/IZoneMapper.cs, Zone/Zone.cs, Zone/ZoneEnum.cs, Zone/ZoneLoader.cs, Zone/ZoneMapper.cs, app.config, packages.config      
Step 5/5] INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US       
Step 5/5] INFO: Language is forced to cs        
Step 5/5] INFO: Index files     
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: File 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Framework\Service.Referential\app.config' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'       
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: File 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Framework\Service.Referential\packages.config' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'      
Step 5/5] INFO: 45 files indexed        
Step 5/5] INFO: Quality profile for cs: custom_profile      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]       
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=2ms     
Step 5/5] ERROR: - [CHECKMARX] - NOTE: Checkmarx scan is canceled;      
Step 5/5] Error while retrieving Checkmarx settings from ******* Database.      
Step 5/5] Please make sure Checkmarx credentials are configured. [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: File 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Api\WebServices\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]        
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx]       
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Retrieving Checkmarx scan results for current module [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Getting Checkmarx configuration data from ******* Database.     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx] (done) | time=6ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the '*******.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.       
Step 5/5] INFO: -------------  Scan WebServices     
Step 5/5] INFO: Base dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Api\WebServices       
Step 5/5] INFO: Working dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\.*******\mod12      
Step 5/5] INFO: Source paths: Bootstrap/OwinBootstrapper.cs, Bootstrap/SignalRAuthenticationMiddleware.cs, Bootstrap/Startup.cs, Common/FakeSsoMiddleware.cs, Common/ISsoConfiguration.cs, Common/SsoConfiguration.cs, Common/ISgmHttpClientV2.cs, Common/SgmHttpClientV2.cs, Controller/AuthenticationController.cs, Controller/BalanceController.cs, Controller/GapPerCurrencyController.cs, Controller/MemoryController.cs, Controller/ReferentialController.cs, Controller/IOwinContext.cs, Controller/OwinContext.cs, Controller/ReportController.cs, Controller/UserController.cs, Entities/Authentication/UsersModel.cs, Entities/Authentication/EnvironmentDetails.cs, Entities/Authentication/LoginResponse.cs, Entities/Authentication/UserAccount.cs, Filters/ExceptionFilter.cs, Notificator.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, Repositories/IUserRepository.cs, Repositories/UserRepository.cs, Settings/ClientMessagingSection.cs, Settings/ConfigurationProvider.cs, Settings/IConfigurationProvider.cs, UserAuthentication/IUserFinder.cs, UserAuthentication/UserFinder.cs, UserAuthentication/UserInformation.cs, WebService.cs, Scripts/jquery-1.6.4-vsdoc.js, Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js, Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js, Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js, Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js, app.config, packages.config      
Step 5/5] INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US       
Step 5/5] INFO: Language is forced to cs        
Step 5/5] ERROR: - [CHECKMARX] - NOTE: Checkmarx scan is canceled;      
Step 5/5] INFO: Index files     
Step 5/5] Error while retrieving Checkmarx settings from ******* Database.      
Step 5/5] Please make sure Checkmarx credentials are configured. [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: 33 files indexed        
Step 5/5] INFO: Quality profile for cs: custom_profile      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]       
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]        
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx]       
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Retrieving Checkmarx scan results for current module [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Getting Checkmarx configuration data from ******* Database.     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx] (done) | time=1ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the '*******.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.       
Step 5/5] INFO: -------------  Scan Service.Technical.Tests     
Step 5/5] INFO: Base dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Tests\Service.Technical.Tests     
Step 5/5] INFO: Working dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\.*******\mod5       
Step 5/5] INFO: Test paths: Authentication/AuthenticationServiceTest.cs, Cache/SlidingExpirationProviderTest.cs, MemoryCacheManagerTest.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, app.config, packages.config     
Step 5/5] INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US       
Step 5/5] INFO: Language is forced to cs        
Step 5/5] INFO: Index files     
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: File 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Tests\Service.Technical.Tests\app.config' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'       
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: File 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Tests\Service.Technical.Tests\packages.config' is ignored because it doesn't belong to the forced language 'cs'      
Step 5/5] INFO: 4 files indexed     
Step 5/5] INFO: Quality profile for cs: custom_profile      
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Property missing: '*******.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.        
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: No roslyn issues report not found for this project.        
Step 5/5] ERROR: - [CHECKMARX] - NOTE: Checkmarx scan is canceled;      
Step 5/5] Error while retrieving Checkmarx settings from ******* Database.      
Step 5/5] Please make sure Checkmarx credentials are configured. [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]       
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=2ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]        
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx]       
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Retrieving Checkmarx scan results for current module [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Getting Checkmarx configuration data from ******* Database.     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx] (done) | time=1ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the '*******.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.       
Step 5/5] INFO: -------------  Scan Service.Technical       
Step 5/5] INFO: Base dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\Sites\CashBalanceSheet\WebService\Framework\Service.Technical       
Step 5/5] INFO: Working dir: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\.*******\mod6       
Step 5/5] INFO: Source paths: Attribute/ColumnAttribute.cs, Cache/BaseCachingProvider.cs, Cache/CacheContent.cs, Cache/CachedItem.cs, Cache/ICachedItem.cs, Cache/ICachingProvider.cs, Cache/IMemoryCacheManager.cs, Cache/ISlidingExpirationProvider.cs, Cache/MemoryCacheManager.cs, Cache/SlidingExpirationProvider.cs, Export/Csv/CsvExporter.cs, Export/Csv/ICsvExporter.cs, Dao/DatabaseConnection.cs, Dao/IDatabaseConnection.cs, Export/ExportType.cs, Logger/ILoggable.cs, Logger/ILogger.cs, Logger/Logger.cs, OpenXml/Cell/CellEditor.cs, OpenXml/Cell/CellReferenceGenerator.cs, OpenXml/Cell/CellType.cs, OpenXml/Cell/ICellEditor.cs, OpenXml/Document/ExcelCreator.cs, OpenXml/Document/IExcelCreator.cs, OpenXml/Document/SpreadSheetExplorer.cs, Export/Excel/ExcelFileData.cs, Export/Excel/ExcelExporter.cs, Export/Excel/ExportOptions.cs, Export/Excel/IExcelExporter.cs, OpenXml/FlatTable/BaseTableEditor.cs, OpenXml/FlatTable/ITableEditor.cs, OpenXml/FlatTable/LargeTableEditor.cs, OpenXml/Sheet/ISheetEditor.cs, OpenXml/Sheet/SheetEditor.cs, OpenXml/Sheet/SheetInfo.cs, OpenXml/Style/IStyleEditor.cs, OpenXml/Style/Style.cs, OpenXml/Style/StyleEditor.cs, OpenXml/Template/ExcelTemplate.cs, OpenXml/Tools/AttributeAccessor.cs, OpenXml/Tools/IAttributeAccessor.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, Serializer/AvroSerializer.cs, Serializer/AvroSurrogate.cs, Serializer/ISerializer.cs, Serializer/XmlSerializer.cs, Zipper/Gzipper.cs, Zipper/IZipper.cs, app.config, packages.config       
Step 5/5] INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US       
Step 5/5] INFO: Language is forced to cs        
Step 5/5] INFO: Index files     
Step 5/5] INFO: 0 files indexed     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]        
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx]       
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Retrieving Checkmarx scan results for current module [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Getting Checkmarx configuration data from ******* Database.     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx] (done) | time=2ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]      
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.Referential_5583\output-cs'     
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\WebServices_0382\output-cs'     
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.Technical_4347\output-cs'       
Step 5/5] Please make sure Checkmarx credentials are configured. [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.60.0]     
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.Referential_5583\output-cs\metrics.pb      
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\WebServices_0382\output-cs\metrics.pb      
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.Technical_4347\output-cs\metrics.pb        
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\LiquidityRatio_1078\output-cs\metrics.pb       
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\LiquidityRatio_1078\output-cs'      
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Snapshot_4057\output-cs'        
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\WebServices.TopShelf.Host_6778\output-cs'       
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.GapPerCurrency_6549\output-cs'      
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.CashBalanceSheet_5820\output-cs\metrics.pb     
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.CashBalanceSheet_5820\output-cs'        
Step 5/5] WARNING: WARN: Protobuf file not found: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\.*******qube\out\Service.Authentication_2775\output-cs\metrics.pb       
Step 5/5] INFO: Importing 11 Roslyn reports     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=2566ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]     
Step 5/5] INFO: Aggregating the HTML reports from D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\SonarResultWeb\dotCover.html        
Step 5/5] INFO: Parsing the dotCover report D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\SonarResultWeb\dotCover\src\1.html
...
...
...     
Step 5/5] INFO: Parsing the dotCover report D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\SonarResultWeb\dotCover\src\187.html      
Step 5/5] INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: D:\TeamCity\BuildAgent1\work\60852095be87e569\SonarResultWeb\dotCover.html       
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=513ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=5ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=141ms     
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer        
Step 5/5] INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms      
Step 5/5] INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the '*******.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.       
Step 5/5] INFO: 166 files had no CPD blocks     
Step 5/5] INFO: Calculating CPD for 355 files       
Step 5/5] INFO: CPD calculation finished        
Step 5/5] INFO: Analysis report generated in 2170ms, dir size=2 MB      
Step 5/5] INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 1671ms, zip size=1 MB        
Step 5/5] INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 577ms       
Step 5/5] INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:8080/dashboard/index/Service.CashBalanceSheet      
Step 5/5] INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report      
Step 5/5] INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:8080/api/ce/task?id=AWNeg6xPsvK0c0fsechK       
Step 5/5] INFO: Task total time: 21.128 s       
Step 5/5] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
Step 5/5] INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS       
Step 5/5] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
Step 5/5] INFO: Total time: 23.908s     
Step 5/5] INFO: Final Memory: 71M/791M      
Step 5/5] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------        
Step 5/5] The SonarQube Scanner has finished
```

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot suggests (from the name we can see) that the .NET solution that you are analyzing contains only test projects - for which the main metrics are not computed. This would explain why you don't get the ncloc at project level.

You might want to take a look at the following documentation which explains how detection of test projects work with the Scanner for MSBuild: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Miscellaneous+Advanced+Usages

Comment: I validated to make sure that correct source code is configured for analysis (pardon me for the name, I renamed it in the screenshot to hide the actual name, should have used better name, my bad). But actual code is configured for analysis and Vulnerabilities, Code Smells, and Coverage is correctly displayed